# Texture mapping with nodes on walls

Tags: texturing, node-editor, vector-mapping

So I'm using nodes to make my brick texture tile, but it always get stretched on one side of the wall. [image: Here you can see how it gets stretched]  It's just one plane subdivided and extended faces. How do I make it look same on all walls?

Comment: You need to use a box projection, instead of flat

Answer (score 1):

You have to unwrap your wall: In the 3D view, in Edit mode, select your whole mesh and press U, and choose for example Smart UV Project or Cube Projection option, then in the Node Editor plug the UV output of your Texture Coordinate node into your Image Texture node, then in UV/Image Editor, rotate or scale the parts of mesh you want so that the bricks appear correctly in your 3D view.

Comment: It kinda works, but then I have to adjust every face. However, if I use the texture coordinate with Cube as an object, it works just as i wanted it to.

Comment: Neverming, important part was switching the projection on Image Texture node to Box.

Comment: You can also use, texture painting.

Answer (score -2):

So I just had to switch projection on Image Texture node to Box.